# \uD83D\uDCCC keep showing up in code I've inherited. What does this unicode sequence do?

Tags: unicode, code-injection

I've been reading about [code injection using unicode sequences](https://medium.com/dotnetsafer/trojan-source-in-dotnet-25f6ce190c1a) and have been using a tool from [Dotnetsafer](https://github.com/dotnetsafer/TrojanSourceDetector4Dotnet) to locate sequences in a codebad I've inherited.  This sequence `\uD83D\uDCCC` keeps coming up:

An example:

```
appears as: [588]                             __builder5.AddMarkupContent(51, "??");
actual    : [588]                             __builder5.AddMarkupContent(51, "\uD83D\uDCCC");
```

What is this sequence?  Why would the code be injecting it into HTML?

EDIT 1: I've looked up the sequence and the only thing remotely useful that I've found is https://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=D83D+DCCC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the UTF-16 code units that encode [the Unicode character U+1F4CC](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F4CC) (the pushpin emoji ).

How could you have found out?

1. Look up [U+D83D](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+D83D) and [U+DCCC](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+DCCC) and find out that they are not actual Unicode characters, but high and low surrogates respectively, meaning they are [used in UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)
2. [Google for "D83D DCCC"](https://www.google.com/search?q=D83D%20DCCC) and [find this page](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F4CC) which explicitly lists those as the UTF-16 encoding of the pushpin emoji.

Actually, come to think of it, you could just skip step #1 ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I did see this search result but since the numbers were nothing like the pair I was querying it didn't register what was going on.